# My UUID is valid for smartphone samsung j5 but not for my Moverio BT-350. Why?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, uuid

With Unity (therefore in C #) I made an Android phone application that communicates via Bluetooth with the PC windows. The problem is that when I run the apk on the smartphone Samsung j5 everything is fine, when instead I run the same apk on another phone or on the Moverio BT-350 (which is always Android) I can't establish the Bluetooth connection and I get an error . Obviously I change the device's Bluetooth MAC address when I switch from one device to another. What I do not change is the UUID. In fact, I believe the UUID is the problem. But how should I change it? How do I assign a valid UUID?

The same problem I find if I try to communicate the apk with a very trivial program in C # written in Visual Studio. This also works well if I enter the MAC address of the J5, but not if I enter the MAC address of the Moverio or another cell.

For simplicity I report the Windows code of this application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth;
using InTheHand.Net.Sockets;
using InTheHand.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace BluetoothForWindows
{ 
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    // this is the UUID, i have no problem with J5, but i have problem with Moverio
        Guid mUUID = new Guid("c1db6770-a359-11e6-80f5-76304dec7eb7");
        bool connect = false;
        BluetoothClient client;

        public Form1()
        {
            items = new List<string>();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client = new BluetoothClient();
            updateUI("attempting connect");
            // When I set the MAC address of J5, that is 14:9F:3C:92:12:06, 
//I have no problem, when I set the MAC address of Moverio, that is 9C:AE:D3:74:83:D9,
//I have Connection Failed Error 
            BluetoothAddress address = 
            BluetoothAddress.Parse("9C:AE:D3:74:83:D9");
            BluetoothEndPoint endPoint = new BluetoothEndPoint(address, mUUID);
            client.Connect(endPoint);
            updateUI("connect with success");
            connect = true;
}
```

Comment: The point of a UUID is to be unique. If you publish this app to multiple devices, it is no longer unique.

Comment: And how to create new UUIDs that are valid for Moverio and other devices?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=netframework-4.8 ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still don't solve the problem. When I try to connect from the Windows PC to the Android app on Moverio it happens that on Android the app continues to run correctly, while on Windows it stops with the following error message (reported in Italian): System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'Indirizzo richiesto non valido nel proprio contesto 9CAED37483D9:cfb771803d214018ad4ab48855bef91a' (in particular the value of UUID changes each time)

Comment: No idea, then. I've not messed with bluetooth.